# Schedule the copy/move and renaming of a file in Sharepoint with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, office365, power-automate

I've tried a variety of configurations with Microsoft Power Automate to copy/move and rename a file in Sharepoint and am getting nowhere. I've seen a handful of examples using the `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` action, but that's also unsuccessful.

I thought the simplest solution might be to use `Copy file` to the same folder as the existing file, so I could use the `Copy with a new name` option since the file would already exist, but it only appends a `1` to the end of the filename instead of allowing me to insert something customized.

**TL;DR:** Here's a mockup of the steps I desire:

1. Recurrence: Runs on Monday every week before midnight (say 11:30 p.m.)
2. Copy an Excel report file from `Weekly\` to `Weekly\Archive` with the filename changed from `Weekly report.xlsx` to `Weekly report - February 1, 2021.xlsx` where the date is that of the Monday that the flow runs, so next Monday from this post would be `Weekly report - February 8, 2021.xlsx` and so on.

Hopefully, this is possible in Power Automate as moving and renaming a file seems like it should be simple for how powerful this platform is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. As expected, HTTP requests and the like were over-complicating the process. Once I had the metadata, content, *and* properties, I was able to create a valid file without the extension being used twice.

Including an image for future reference.

[image]